# how to using session in NodeJS/ExpressJS - postgreSQL

Tags: node.js, postgresql, session

I'm using express-session / connect-pg-simple modules.

Why they doesn't save session information? And they every changed sid

How can I do That. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pPmw.png)

Anyway.

Im tried server memory store session, No save session way.

They Never saved.

I want to GET /auth/login this session userInfo -> GET / this session must has userInfo.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it accessible and readable, including a minimal reproducible code example. "Enter image description here" does not make sense. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.